# How to use sharex and sharey combined with aspect=equal and adjustable='box-forced' to create subplots with the same scale in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create four subplots, whose axes represent different range of distances [km] in different directions, except for the x-axis of the lower right subplot that represents counts. All the axes of distance should have the same scale in all the subplots. Also, the two subplots on the top should share their y-axes and the two subplots on the left should share their x-axes.

Following this [issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7621) (whose solution works well for equal limits in x and y axes), I have tried several combinations of the sharex, sharey, aspect, and adjustable, parameters without success.

Is there a way to achieve this kind of plot, in particular without affecting any of the axis limits?

Here is my MCVE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
lim1 = [0.,30.]
lim2 = [0.,15.]
lim3 = [0.,75.]
lim4 = [0,5]
xdat = [12.,25.]
ydat = [6.,12.]
zdat = [50.,25.]
cdat = [1,1]
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(221,aspect='equal',adjustable='box-forced')
ax1.plot(xdat,ydat,'o')
ax1.set_xlim(lim1)
ax1.set_ylim(lim2)
ax2 = plt.subplot(222,aspect='equal',adjustable='box-forced',sharey=ax1)
ax2.plot(zdat,ydat,'o') 
ax2.set_xlim(lim3)
ax3 = plt.subplot(223,aspect='equal',adjustable='box-forced',sharex=ax1)
ax3.plot(xdat,zdat,'o')
ax3.set_ylim(lim3)
ax4 = plt.subplot(224)
ax4.plot(cdat,zdat,'o')
ax4.set_xlim(lim4)
ax4.set_ylim(lim3)
plt.show()
```

I would like to get something like the plot in the image below, that shows the axes shared as I mentioned above, keeping the original axis limits and the same scale on the different axes of distance.

[image]

I'm currently using:
Platform: Linux Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
matplotlib: 1.5.1
python: 2.7.14

Comment: I guess "same scale" will indeed overconstrain the system. Apart the code works as expected, so how exactly would you like the plot to look like?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest What do you mean by "overconstrain the system"? By the way, I've just updated my question including an image of how roughly the plot should look like.

Comment: The plot you show does not have equal aspect ratios. So if you remove the constraint about equal aspect, the plots looks fine.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The plot doesn't have equal aspect ratios precisely because I removed that constraint (aspect='equal'), just to show how the subplots axes should be shared. But I need that constraint to keep the same scale on the subplot axes.

Comment: Would it be possible to draw an image of what you envision your plot to look like?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ok, I updated the image, that now shows exactly the kind of plot I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the underlying grid to have the plots have different sizes. The different limits would act as the ratio between the sizes of the grid cells.

You then still need to adjust the figure size to have nice spacings and set the aspect of the last subplots which is different from 1.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec

lim1 = [0.,30.]
lim2 = [0.,15.]
lim3 = [0.,75.]
lim4 = [0,5]
xdat = [12.,25.]
ydat = [6.,12.]
zdat = [50.,25.]
cdat = [1,1]

gskw = dict(width_ratios = [np.diff(lim1)[0],np.diff(lim3)[0]],
            height_ratios= [np.diff(lim2)[0],np.diff(lim3)[0]])

gs = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(2,2, **gskw)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,5))

ax1=fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0], aspect="equal",adjustable='box-forced')
ax1.plot(xdat,ydat,'o')

ax2=fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1], aspect="equal",adjustable='box-forced', sharey=ax1)
ax2.plot(zdat,ydat,'o') 

ax3=fig.add_subplot(gs[1,0], aspect="equal",adjustable='box-forced', sharex=ax1)
ax3.plot(xdat,zdat,'o')

asp, = np.diff(lim4)/np.diff(lim3)
ax4=fig.add_subplot(gs[1,1], aspect=asp)
ax4.plot(cdat,zdat,'o')

ax1.set_xlim(lim1)
ax1.set_ylim(lim2)
ax2.set_xlim(lim3)
ax3.set_ylim(lim3)
ax4.set_xlim(lim4)
ax4.set_ylim(lim3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was searching for.