# How to set equal axis range for seaborn plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to make scatter plot particularly jointplot with seaborn.
I need for x and y axis to have same scale, i.e. make cirle circular, but not the same limit.

For example:

```
x = np.linspace(75,77,100)
y = np.linspace(1785.5, 1786,100)
```

And it shouldn't look like this:

[image]

I tried adding:

```
plt.axis("equal")
```

and square, scale but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sharing axes between subplots usually doesn't go well with changing aspect ratios.  To set the aspect ratio of the main subplot, you can try `g = sns.jointplot(...)` and then `g.ax_joint.set_aspect('equal')`. To also adjust the right subplot, you could experiment with e.g. `g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.7, bottom=0.3, left=0.12)`or changing the fig-size.    See e.g. [How to use sharex and sharey combined with aspect=equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351874/how-to-use-sharex-and-sharey-combined-with-aspect-equal-and-adjustable-box-forc)
`